# Scale column values on a table in Grafana

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I have a query in Prometheus QL which show values as a table in Grafana. My issue is that a value `updated` is in epoch time and in order to show human readable date I would need to multiply by 1000. There is a way to multiply value and then show? Not sure if it is possible somehow by tuning the below query or this feature is not supported at all in Grafana. I've already made some attempts but I had no luck.

This is my query:

```
min(helm_chart_info{chart=~"$chart", exported_namespace=~"$namespace", release=~"$release"}) by (chart, release, exported_namespace, updated, version) != 2
```

Comment: Multiply it in the query. It should work as intuitively expected `metric{label="foo"}*1000`

Comment: No unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: I am surprised. It work on the [demo site](http://demo.robustperception.io:9090/graph?g0.range_input=1h&g0.expr=alertmanager_config_last_reload_success_timestamp_seconds*1000&g0.tab=1). Could you post your expression with the multiplication ?